# How to add query string param and do the paging

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, paging

I am trying to implement `GridView` with manual paging. i want to add a `query string param` for paging. this is completely for `SEO` and it is `absolutely required`.  The code is already published on website and has about 500 entries(posts in `gridview`).

Now company wants me to do a querystring param so search engine can go through all the pages and captures it. right now search engines are seeing only the page 1 on gridview. thats what i came to know from SEO team.

I really dont have any idea on how to do this. please help. i can not really change all the code because it would mess up all the pages which are already LIVE.

## GirdView Code

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" AllowPaging="true" ID="entriesGridView" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
DataKeyNames="EntryId" ShowHeader="False" OnRowDataBound="entriesGridView_RowDataBound"
CssClass="grid" OnPageIndexChanging="entriesGridView_PageIndexChanging" PageSize="20">
<PagerStyle CssClass="pager"></PagerStyle>
      <Columns>
            // some template / bound fields
      </Columns>
      <EmptyDataTemplate>
            // empty results text....
      </EmptyDataTemplate>
      <EmptyDataRowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
   </asp:GridView>
```

## Code-Behind

```
protected void entriesGridView_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
      LoadEntriesGridView(false, false, false, sqlCriteria);
      entriesGridView.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
      entriesGridView.DataBind();
}
```

## DataSource

```
public static EntryCollection LoadForCriteriaWithJoin(string sqlCriteria, bool isEmailQuery, bool isFullNameQuery, string sortExpression)
      {
            //DEFAULT SORT EXPRESSION
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortExpression)) sortExpression = "OrderBy";
            //CREATE THE DYNAMIC SQL TO LOAD OBJECT
            var selectQuery = new StringBuilder();
            selectQuery.Append("SELECT");
            selectQuery.Append(" CE.* ");
            selectQuery.Append("FROM EntryTable CE ");
            selectQuery.Append("JOIN ContestantsTable CC ");
            selectQuery.Append("ON CE.ContestantId = CC.ContestantId ");

            string whereClause = null;
            if (isEmailQuery)
                  whereClause = "WHERE CE.IsApproved = 1 AND CC.Email = @EmailAddress";
            else if (isFullNameQuery)
                  whereClause = "WHERE CE.IsApproved = 1 AND CC.FirstName + ' ' + CC.LastName LIKE '%' + @FullName + '%'" +
                        "OR CE.CName LIKE '%' + @FullName + '%'" +
                         "OR CE.CTitle LIKE '%' + @FullName + '%'" +
                          "OR CE.Answer1 + ' ' + CE.Answer2 + ' ' + Answer3 LIKE '%' + @FullName + '%'";
            else
                  whereClause = "WHERE CE.IsApproved = 2";     // returning Empty result...

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(sqlCriteria))
                  selectQuery.Append(whereClause);

            selectQuery.Append(" ORDER BY " + sortExpression);
            var database = T.I.Database;
            var selectCommand = database.GetSqlStringCommand(selectQuery.ToString());

            if (isEmailQuery)
                  database.AddInParameter(selectCommand, "@Email", System.Data.DbType.String, sqlCriteria);
            if (isFullNameQuery)
                  database.AddInParameter(selectCommand, "@FullName", System.Data.DbType.String, sqlCriteria);

            //EXECUTE THE COMMAND
            var results = new EntryCollection();
            using (var dr = database.ExecuteReader(selectCommand))
            {
                  while (dr.Read())
                  {
                        var entry = new Entry();
                        MWCompetitionsEntry.LoadDataReader(entry, dr);
                        results.Add(entry);
                  }
                  dr.Close();
            }
            return results;
      }
```

Comment: please post your `entriesGridView` data source including the query so we can see what are you doing and what you should change.

Comment: I may be horribly out of date here, but I thought most search engines stopped looking at query strings ages ago? Hence "SEO-friendly URLs" e.g. `/items/pages/1` etc. etc.

Comment: please have look at the data source in my question...